# Table border-right doesn't work in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, border

I have added `border-right` to my table and it works perfectly, but when I view it in Outlook the border wraps around the whole table

Here's my fiddle of the table border working correctly:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39bKM/)

Does anyone know how to only show the border on the right in Outlook?

Comment: try this out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39bKM/5/) - `<td height="666" align="left" id="column1" style="border: 1px solid red; border-width: 0 1px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px">`

Comment: Nope, not working. It's still creating a border around the whole table

Comment: Try putting: border-top: none; border-bottom: none; border-left: none; border-right: 1px solid red;

Comment: Yes, or just the `border-right` one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding this code:

```
border-top: none; border-bottom: none; border-left: none; border-right: 1px solid red;
```

Now it works!